# Getting unique random line (at each script run) from an text file with perl

Tags: perl

Having an text file like the next one called "input.txt"

```
some field1a | field1b | field1c
...another approx 1000 lines....
fielaNa | field Nb | field Nc
```

I can choose any field delimiter.

**Need a script, what at every discrete run will get one unique (never repeated) random line from this file, until used all lines.**

My solution: I added one column into a file, so have

```
0|some field1a | field1b | field1c
...another approx 1000 lines....
0|fielaNa | field Nb | field Nc
```

and processing it with the next code:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use List::Util;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
my $file = "./input.txt";

#read all lines into array and shuffle them
open(my $fh, "<:utf8", $file);
my @lines = List::Util::shuffle map { chomp $_; $_ } <$fh>;
close $fh;

#search for the 1st line what has 0 at the start
#change the 0 to 1
#and rewrite the whole file

my $random_line;
for(my $i=0; $i<=$#lines; $i++) {
    if( $lines[$i] =~ /^0/ ) {
        $random_line = $lines[$i];
        $lines[$i] =~ s/^0/1/;
        open($fh, ">:utf8", $file);
        print $fh join("\n", @lines);
        close $fh;
        last;
    }
}
$random_line = "1|NO|more|lines" unless( $random_line =~ /\w/ );

do_something_with_the_fields(split /\|/, $random_line))
exit;
```

It is an working solution, but not very nice one, because:

- the line order is changing at each script run
- not concurrent script-run safe.

How to write it more effective and more elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program uses the [`Tie::File`](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aFile) module to open your `input.txt` file as well as an `indices.txt` file.

If `indices.txt` is empty then it is initialised with the indices of all the records in `input.txt` in a shuffled order.

Each run, the index at the end of the list is removed and the corresponding input record displayed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
use List::Util 'shuffle';

tie my @input, 'Tie::File', 'input.txt'
        or die qq(Unable to open "input.txt": $!);

tie my @indices, 'Tie::File', 'indices.txt'
        or die qq(Unable to open "indices.txt": $!);

@indices = shuffle(0..$#input) unless @indices;

my $index = pop @indices;
print $input[$index];
```

---

**Update**

I have modified this solution so that it populates a new `indices.txt` file only if it doesn't already exist and not, as before, simply when it is empty. That means a new sequence of records can be printed simply by deleting the `indices.txt` file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
use List::Util 'shuffle';

my ($input_file, $indices_file) = qw( input.txt indices.txt );

tie my @input, 'Tie::File', $input_file
        or die qq(Unable to open "$input_file": $!);

my $first_run = not -f $indices_file;

tie my @indices, 'Tie::File', $indices_file
        or die qq(Unable to open "$indices_file": $!);

@indices = shuffle(0..$#input) if $first_run;

@indices or die "All records have been displayed";
my $index = pop @indices;
print $input[$index];
```

Comment: Thank you. It is nearly my new solution. :) I'm using $index = splice(@indices, rand @indices, 1) ... accept.

Comment: @novacik: That is pointless. The indices are already in a random order. Choosing from them randomly instead of linearly won't make them any more 'random'. I chose to use `pop` because that would delete from the end of the file and so be fastest.

Comment: Mean - im using splice/rand without shuffle.

Comment: @novacik: ah OK. What don't you like about `shuffle`? `List::Util` has been in core Perl since v5.7 so your pretty much bound to have it installed.

Comment: IMO when shuffle the "tied file" the module will rewrite the whole file, when splice something from the middle, will rewrite only from the middle to end of file. But, maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: @novacik: It is the other way around! In my code the list of indices is generated in memory and shuffled *once* before being written to disk. After that the *last* number is popped from the list which only requires a truncation of the file: all contents remain unchanged. Your variation removes records randomly from within the file forcing the entire file to be rewritten.

Comment: Just now really tried your code. It is not working. :( Try it yourself! Make the input.txt with 5 lines. Run your script 10 times. All 10 times will give an random line, but it should only 5 times, because only 5 lines are in the input.txt and results should be unique. You should shuffle the @indices, not the 1..$#input.

Comment: @novacik: read the program. Once the `indices.txt` is tied to the array, *if it is empty* it is populated with the shuffled list of indices. That means that once all the lines from the file have been printed the indices file is repopulated and the process starts again, printing the records in a different random order.

Comment: @novacik: I have updated my solution so that the `indices.txt` file has to be deleted before a new sequence is started.

Comment: OK, Now it is working like charm. Shuffling only once and only shortening the file with poping only last line. Brilliant! :)  Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

What about keeping a shuffled list of the line numbers in a different file, removing the first one each time you use it? Some locking might be needed to asure concurent script-run safety.

Comment: I was going to suggest just adding another column with the line numbers so they could be rewritten in order, but this is a much better way to do it since you don't need to modify data file at all.

Comment: Thanx for the idea! Maybe this will be the solution. Honestly, i hoped in some CPAN module idea, but when nobody comes with simpler solution, will follow your advice. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

From [perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html).

> [How do I select a random line from a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-select-a-random-line-from-a-file%3f)
>
> Short of loading the file into a database or pre-indexing the lines in
>   the file, there are a couple of things that you can do.
>
> Here's a reservoir-sampling algorithm from the Camel Book:
>
> ```
> srand;
> rand($.) < 1 && ($line = $_) while <>;
> ```
>
> This has a significant advantage in space over reading the whole file
>   in. You can find a proof of this method in The Art of Computer
>   Programming, Volume 2, Section 3.4.2, by Donald E. Knuth.
>
> You can use the File::Random module which provides a function for that
>   algorithm:
>
> ```
> use File::Random qw/random_line/;
> my $line = random_line($filename);
> ```
>
> Another way is to use the Tie::File module, which treats the entire
>   file as an array. Simply access a random array element.

All Perl programmers should take the time to read the FAQ.

**Update:** To get a unique random line each time you're going to have to store state. The easiest way to store the state is to remove the lines that you've used from the file.

Comment: The random line should be unique (Need a script, what at every discrete run will get one unique (never repeated) random line from this file, until used all lines)

Comment: All Perl programmers should take the time to read the whole question :-)

Comment: I know how to get an random line from a file. But in this case, i need get __unique__ random line at each run. Citing the FAQ is easy - but it is not an solution in this case. Thanx anyway for your reply.

Comment: @Dave Cross: but thanx for the Tie::File idea. It seems be nice.